# How to get user statistics using the $Monitoring cube via XMLA?

Tags: iccube

I have successfully enabled the `$Monitoring` cube by setting the `<activated>true</activated>` to `true` in de the `icCube.xml`-file.

I use the cubes using the [Excel XMLA interface](https://www.iccube.com/support/documentation/user_guide/integration/excel.php) and using an icCube-admin account the %Monitoring cube is visible and accessible.

All of my colleagues have their own icCube-account and now I really want to get some stats about which cubes are used by who (when, how many times, etc.). Is their any to do this using the Excel XMLA interface?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In the $Monitoring cube, you have the User and Time dimensions (amongst others). So you can select statistics per User and Time. You can see all the available stats in the Measure dimension itself.

Comment: Thank you, Marc. 
I can see the User and Time-dimensions in the cube. However, for some reason I cannot expand the User dimension. The only thing I can see is the entry `User L`.

Do I need to enable logging per user separately?

Comment: Might be that nothing has been reported for users yet.

Comment: That was my first thought too, but that not the case. I have seen colleagues use the cubes and also when I go to 'Monitoring' > 'Runtime' > 'Completed Request' there are some other users listed. Do I need to refresh or reload the $Monitoring cube manually?

Comment: try the following MDX. Does it give results? select {[Measures].[Total MDX Request Time],[Measures].[Total MDX Request Count]} on 0
, {[User].[User].[User L].members}* [Time].[Time].[ALL].&[2018].&[2018-07-01] on 1
from $Monitoring

Comment: Thank you, Arthur. 

Your MDX gives no result. However this one does gives some result:

`select {[Measures].[Total MDX Request Time],[Measures].[Total MDX Request Count]} on 0 , {[User].[All Users]}* [Time].[Time].[ALL].&[2018].&[2018-07-01] on 1 from $Monitoring`

So, when reporting on All Users it works fine, I just can seem to figure out how to drill down.